# Simple Datepicker code Compatibility Issue - works on Firefox 6.0.2 and IE9.0.8, not on most recent chrome or IE8

Tags: jquery, cross-browser, datepicker, compatibility, jquery-ui-datepicker

I have the following code:

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.6.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script  type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $("#datepicker1").datepicker({

        })
    })
</script>


<div class="demo">

   <p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker1"></p>

</div>
</form>
```

I've tried versions 1.7.2 , same problem. It's part a larger solution and this is just what I've pinned the issue down to. I have no idea why the other browsers aren't working with this, any help would be immensely appreciated. Also, First post. ( I did find other posts about compatibility but nothing this simple that would help me understand WHY these things aren't working.)

Comment: Doesn't work in what way? Any errors? Also, I would suggest loading the jquery library before jquery-ui.

Comment: I can't see any errors, it simply just doesn't pull the date picker into the text box. You should be able to just click the text box and have it pop out the same as in Firefox but it just acts as a standard TextBox. Also - Thanks for the quick reply!

Comment: Just tried a fiddle for this in Chrome: http://jsfiddle.net/jzMav/ Works fine. Did you try correcting the order that the you load the libraries?

Comment: Very bizarre. I did indeed try to swap the order of those and yeah it's still doing the same. Is it possible the issue lies server side, then?

Comment: Unlikely as it's a client side issue, if you have any other code on the page at all add it to the jsfiddle and test in the relevant browsers.

Comment: Thanks  Amalea. That's it - it's just those jquery calls that seem to be breaking it for some reason =\

Answer (score 1):

The solution was bizarre and maybe there was a separate reason for it, but I simply stopped referencing the .js files by address and saved them local to the server. 
No more issues.